How to fix a wobbly Satori EZ3 quill?
I have a Satori EZ3 quill on my bike. It's adjustable by a clamping mechanism. However, when clamped, it still wobbles at the point where the angles bar is clamped onto the stem. The clamping strength is adjustable, but it seems the part it clamps onto, a short grooved tube perpendicular to the angled arm, is wobbling itself.

In this image, it's the point behind the logo, where the arm clamps onto the stem.
I'm trying to contact the manufacturer as well, but in the meantime, does anyone know how to fix the wobble? Or am I SOL and do I get a new quill?

Could you add some photos of your stem please?   I've added a stock image in the meantime.

Which part is wobbly?
Wobbly where the quill locks into the steerer tube?
Wobbly where stem clamps the handle bar?
Wobbly at the adjustable angle lock?

@MindDBike That last one. I'll clarify my question.

@Criggie thanks for adding the image. I'll try to snap a picture later, however, the problematic part isn't really visible from the outside.

After taking it off, it seems to be unrepairable, at least not by just tightening a screw or something similar, so I've bought a replacement.
